# Perl 5.14 source - Sample program failing

Tags: c++, linux, perl

Perl 5.14 source - Sample program failing

I'm trying to execute the below program on Linux 64 with libperl.so built with 5.14 source
and i'm getting an abort in the location

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00002abdc0eb2656 in Perl_sv_2mortal () from ./libperl.so
(gdb) where
#0  0x00002abdc0eb2656 in Perl_sv_2mortal () from ./libperl.so
#1  0x00000000004010ed in PerlPower ()
#2  0x0000000000401335 in main ()
(gdb)
```

My program:

```
#include <EXTERN.h>
#include <perl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;
static void PerlPower(int a, int b)
{
    dSP;            /* initialize stack pointer */
    ENTER;          /* everything created after here */
    SAVETMPS;       /* ...is a temporary variable. */
    PUSHMARK(SP);       /* remember the stack pointer */
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(a))); /* push the base onto the stack */
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(b))); /* push the exponent onto stack */
    PUTBACK;        /* make local stack pointer global */
    call_pv("expo", G_SCALAR);  /* call the function */
    SPAGAIN;        /* refresh stack pointer *
                   /* pop the return value from stack */
    printf("%d to the %dth power is %d.\n", a, b, POPi);
    PUTBACK;
    FREETMPS;       /* free that return value */
    LEAVE;          /* ...and the XPUSHed "mortal" args. */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    char *my_argv[] = { "", "power.pl" };

    PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc, &argv, &env);
    my_perl = perl_alloc();
    perl_construct(my_perl);

    perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, 2, my_argv, (char **)NULL);
    PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
    perl_run(my_perl);

    PerlPower(3, 4);
             /*** Compute 3 ** 4 ***/

    perl_destruct(my_perl);
    perl_free(my_perl);
    PERL_SYS_TERM();
}
```

power.pl contains the below statements

```
sub expo {
my ($a, $b) = @_;
return $a ** $b;
}
```

The above sample C and perl program was taken from the link http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html#Evaluating-a-Perl-statement-from-your-C-program

I'm using the below compiler options

Compiler:

```
cc='cc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DTHREADS_HAVE_PIDS -DDEBUGGING -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
optimize='-O2 -fmessage-length=0 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -Wall -pipe',
cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DTHREADS_HAVE_PIDS -DDEBUGGING -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement'
ccversion='', gccversion='4.1.2 20070115 (prerelease) (SUSE Linux)', gccosandvers=''
intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
alignbytes=8, prototype=define
```

Can you please help me to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of `power.pl`.

Answer (score 2):

I got one too, I got the win32 equivalent      `Faulting application power.exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module perl514.dll, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x000c155f.`
but I also got an error message :)

```
$ power.exe
Can't open perl script "power.pl": No such file or directory
```

After copying power.pl from embed it works as expected

```
$ cat power.pl
sub expo {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    return $a ** $b;
}

$ power.exe
3 to the 4th power is 81.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was while compiling the source i hadn't specified the new 5.14.2 header files location. I copied both the c and perl file to the folder containing new header file of 5.14.2 and compiling with below options resolved the problem

g++ -o test_perl test_perl.c -I . -L .  -g `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:LD_LIBRARY_PATH;export LD_LIBRARY_PATH